# Windows 10 VM install stuck on a loop with OOBE-type errors

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, installation

**Symptoms**

When installing as guest OS on a VirtualBox VM, Windows 10 installation process won't get past the OOBE "Something went wrong" error screens.

Accompanying error codes encountered:

- OOBEKEYBOARD
- OOBEEULA
- OOBESETTINGSMULTIPAGE

Long wait periods when Setup shows "Just a moment..." are interspersed throughout the process.

In some cases it is possible to select the "Skip" option, although the installation process reaches a point where this option is no longer available.

[image: Error screenshot]

Clicking on "Try again", even multiple times, does not help.

**Steps attempted**

- Following [Microsoft's own documentation](https://archive.is/VMvRu):

  > **Workaround**
  >
  > For Issue 1 ("Something went wrong - But you can try again"), click Try again  at the bottom of the screen. The OOBE process should continue as expected.
  >
  > For Issue 2 ("Just a moment..."), press and hold the power button until the system turns off, and then turn on the system again. The OOBE process should resume and complete as expected.

  does not help - the process keeps getting stuck at the same points.
- When any of the errors above are shown

  open Command Prompt (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) and type

  ```
  %windir%\System32\Sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /reboot
  ```

  to force a reboot and restart/resume the setup  process, but I keep getting stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Increase the number of processors assigned to the VM to at least 2.

- From Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager:

  Machine → Settings → System → Processor tab

  increase the number to 2 or more.